# How do I convert a component with a constructor function and props, to a functional component using hooks and props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to optimize images on my web app on the go. I'm trying to **modify code that works as a class function with a constructor**, into a **functional component that uses hooks**.

The reason I need it to be a functional component is that I need props to be passed. I need it to be reusable. I need to do this: If I can do this in the code with the constructor, please please let me know or point me somewhere, that's a viable option.

I need to be reusable so that I can use it on all my img elements, in this respect:

`<img src={props.image} />`

I've only been able to achieve this with a functional component. This is why I'm trying to make this into a functional component. To achieve a specific problem I am unable to do because of that constructor function.

This is the working Constructor code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TestImage from "./test-image.png";

export default class ImgOptimise extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      width: 0
    };
    this.imgRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const width = this.imgRef.current.clientWidth;
    this.setState({
      width
    });
  }

  render() {
    // Destructure props and state
    const { src, alt, options = {}, ext = "jpg" } = this.props;
    const { width } = this.state;

    // Create an empty query string
    let queryString = "";

    // If width is specified, otherwise use auto-detected width
    options["w"] = options["w"] || width;

    // Loop through option object and build queryString
    Object.keys(options).map((option, i) => {
      return (queryString += `${i < 1 ? "?" : "&"}${option}=${
        options[option]
      }`);
    });

    return (
      <figure ref={this.imgRef}>
        {// If the container width has been set, display the image else null
        width > 0 ? (
          <>
            <img src={TestImage} alt="test" />
          </>
        ) : null}
      </figure>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ImgOptimise />, rootElement);
```

---

This is my code for translating it to a functional component using hooks

https://codesandbox.io/live/Wr7V4

Full Code below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TestImage from "./test-image.png";

const ImgOptimise = props => {
  // Destructure props and state
  const { src, alt, options = {}, ext = "jpg" } = useEffect(0);
  const [width] = useState(0);


  const imgRef = React.createRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const width = imgRef.current.clientWidth;
  }, []);

  // Create an empty query string
  let queryString = "";
  // If width is specified, otherwise use auto-detected width
  options["w"] = options["w"] || width;
  // Loop through option object and build queryString
  Object.keys(options).map((option, i) => {
    return (queryString += `${i < 1 ? "?" : "&"}${option}=${options[option]}`);
  });
  return (
    // If the container width has been set, display the image else null
    <figure ref={imgRef}>
      {// If the container width has been set, display the image else null
      width > 0 ? (
        <>
          <img src={TestImage} />
        </>
      ) : null}
    </figure>
  );
};
export default ImgOptimise;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ImgOptimise />, rootElement);
```

ERROR: `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'src' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.`

something to do with this, I'm not sure how to destructure it properly:

`//Constructor
const { src, alt, options = {}, ext = "jpg" } = this.props;`

`//Hooks
const { src, alt, options = {}, ext = "jpg" } = useEffect(0);`

I'm also not sure if I translated this properly

```
    this.imgRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const width = this.imgRef.current.clientWidth;
    this.setState({
      width
    });
  }
```

to this:

```
 const [width] = useState(0);
  // const [nameState , setNameState] = useState(props);
  const imgRef = React.createRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const width = imgRef.current.clientWidth;
  }, []);
```

Any Help changing this from a class component to a functional component will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Turns out mine was a rookie mistake. I overlooked `this`

Even though my problem has been solved, I will leave the question open as it will be interesting to see this turned into a functional component, because, well, why not?

Comment: Note that you don't *have* to switch, anything you can do with a function component you can also achieve with a class-based one. Looking at your code, it seems like you still have a few misconceptions around what some hooks are used for, especially `useEffect`. I suggest you give the relevant part of the React docs another read, and maybe find one or two more in-depth tutorials out there. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html

Comment: To echo that, the first response should be "why?" Components work perfectly fine, so if things already work, don't spend time changing to something you don't actually _need_ to change. Spend that time on improving something else.

Comment: Thank you @Timo Those docs were my first point of call. Of course, my knowledge is limited, which is why I'm posing this question.  All my research and limited knowledge, as well as many variations of trying to pass props from outside that class component, were not successful. If you know a way, in relation to this code, please, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for that. I'm just trying to solve this particular problem. I don't know how to pass props from outside the class, I searched, tried out many things, but I know it works as a functional component. How can I do that with this code?

Comment: Not sure I understand. For a functional component you effect properties passing using `const blah = function(props) { do something with props }`, and for a class effect that same thing using `class Blah extends Component { constructor(props) { super(props); this.state = { ... }; ... } ... }`. For your functional component, you access the props directly, because it's just a function, for a component class you use `this.props`.

Comment: the links to codesandbox are the same

Comment: @Mike I have been going crazy over this! thank you! That's exactly what I needed. I'm learning as i go

Comment: @JuniusL. See updated code

Comment: @ShingaiMunyuki this is fairly explicitly covered by the React tutorial - if it's been a while, refamiliarise yourself with the basics of React by just running through it again and reading the text rather than just skipping from code block to code block =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are your props, you just need to destructure them, not apply useEffect().

```
const { src, alt, options = {}, ext = "jpg" } = props;
```

For your state, you need to define a function along with your state variable.

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
```

Then call that function to update `width`.

```
setWidth(imgRef.current.clientWidth);
```

More info can be found by searching, e.g. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+convert+react+component+to+hooks&ia=web , which results in some good articles like https://alligator.io/react/converting-to-a-hook/

Comment: This actually made me understand more, in the context of my problem. It worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!